# Too many symbol fonts declared error

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, luatex

I have discovered a new package `newtxmath` which is sad to be better than `mathptmx`. I also want to use the `bm` package for bold Greek letters.

It works just fine with `mathptmx`, but causes an error with `newtxmath`.

Here is my document (use **LuaLaTex** to compile).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{skull}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{xfrac} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}


\setmainfont{Georgia}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Georgia}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{russian}

\begin{document}

$$
\bm{\Phi}
$$

\end{document}
```

I am sorry for posting so many packages here, but I wasn't able to figure it out which package conflicts with `newtxmath`, because `mathptmx` also loads a math font, so they should both cause, or both not cause a problem (obviuosly, I am wrong here).

Searching through this site I found all answers to be too personal and too specific. Unfortunately, I couldn't apply any of those solutions to me.

Comment: Just a question: Why don't you use `fontspec` in combination with e.g. `unicode-math` to set a math font?

Comment: Which TeX distribution and which version of Lua(La)TeX do you use? I have MacTeX and LuaTeX 0.95; your code doesn't generate an error if I comment out the directive `\usepackage{skull}`, which I have to do as I don't seem to have a package named "skull" on my system.

Comment: @TeXnician - The OP may prefer the appearance of the integral symbols provided by the `newtxmath` package to those provided by, say, the `XITS Math` or `TeX Gyre Termes` math fonts...

Comment: Is the "skull" package proprietary?

Comment: I get no math alphabet error (just error about missing font skull) but do you have an old (pre-2015) latex? That would explain the error. Note also that you are loading `bm` first but as explained in its documentation you need to load it after any package that loads math fonts.

Comment: @Mico there is a skull package in texlive (although something odd as the package is there but not the font) in my setup `tlmgr info skull` ...

Comment: You can remove `mathabx` and `amssymb`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the skull font works fine for me. It is a metafont font, and the mf source is there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah but I need to use xelatex first lualatex isn't triggering maketfm, I seem to remember seeing a report about that somewhere.. The OP's document now works without error in lualatex as well

Comment: you probably do not want to load both babel and polyglossia

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had used pdflatex for the test in a small document), but you are right  lualatex doesn't trigger `mktextfm`.

Comment: @TeXnician Or because `unicode-math` is rather buggy? (Or buggy in combination with other things in its ecosystem - possibly not `unicode-math`'s fault.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your preamble is a bit messy.

Loading `mathabx` and `amssymb` along with `newtxmath` is useless: if you load `mathabx` before `newtxmath`, most of the symbols will be redefined; in the other order, `mathabx` will override most of `newtxmath` symbols.

Also `skull` allocates a math symbol font just for one symbol. It doesn't seem worthy it and it's easy to do without wasting a math group.

The package loading order is very important; in some cases you get conflicts. In particular, `bm` should be loaded after math font packages and after `amsmath`.

Don't load both `babel` and `polyglossia`: they fight each other.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fix-cm}% just to avoid some spurious messages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{skull} % see later
\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb} % not with newtxmath
%\usepackage{mathabx} % not with newtxmath
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{xfrac} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage[russian]{babel} % either babel or polyglossia
\usepackage{polyglossia}    

\setmainlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont{Georgia}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Georgia}

%%% Loading a math symbol font for just one symbol is a big waste
%%% The following lines do the same as skull.sty
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{skulls}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{skulls}{m}{n}{ <-> skull }{}
\newcommand{\skull}{\text{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}


\begin{document}

\[
\bm{\Phi}+\skull
\]

\end{document}
```

Finally, update your TeX system: with XeLaTeX and a properly crafted preamble it's quite rare to incur in the “Too many math fonts” error.

[image]

Comment: Since you're on a mission to clean up and simplify the preamble: Since `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, one may also omit the directive `\usepackage{amsmath}`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I will never do it. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks! Everything works perfectly now. In case of the order of loading the packages you always should apply some magic.